# How can I disable checkstyle rules for tests in gradle?

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

with maven I disabled checkstyle for tests, how can I disable the `checkstyleTest` task  in gradle?

I've tried variations o these separately

```
checkstyle {
  toolVersion = '6.10.1'
  exclude '**/*Test.java'
}
checkstyleTest {
   sourceSets = []
}
```

it all ends up in errors

Answer (score 10):

Apparently you can set the undocumented (maybe underdocumented? maybe it's inherited or something ) `enabled` property on `checkstyleTest` (and to access that in the closure is in no way obvious by the documentation) to `false`.

```
checkstyle {
  toolVersion = '6.10.1'
  checkstyleTest.enabled = false
}
```

Comment: just a minor note: `checkstyleTest.enabled = false` can live outside the checkstyle block as it references the task with the name `checkstyleTest`. the `enabled` property is inherited from `Task`

Answer (score 7):

The cleanest way is to tell Gradle to execute only the Checkstyle tasks that you need, by specifying them like so:

```java
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '6.10.1'
    sourceSets = [project.sourceSets.main]
}
```

Just disabling the unneeded tasks would also work, but I think the above is cleaner.

In the above example, the `checkstyleTest` task will remain in the task list, even though it is not executed. I prefer a clean task list, so you can remove the unused task via

```java
project.tasks.remove(project.tasks['checkstyleTest']);
```

Comment: `Task with path 'checkstyleTest' not found in root project '[...]'` if I add the `.remove()` at the bottom of `build.gradle`. Where should it go?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the below command :
`./gradle build -x checkstyleMain`

Answer (score 0):

```
task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    configFile file("${project.rootDir}/app/checkstyle.xml")
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/androidTest/**'

    classpath = files()
}
```

Comment: please add some more details here

Answer (score 0):

In staticAnalysis block set checkstyleEnabled to false

```
staticAnalysis {
    checkstyleEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As i have already said in another post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772872/how-can-i-disable-checkstyle-rules-for-tests-in-gradle/40373903#40373903)

Simply try this one

```
tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
    ignoreFailures true
    exclude '**/**'
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can set sourceSets to empty array (or [] ) to skip the task.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.CheckstyleExtension.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.CheckstyleExtension:sourceSets

Also you can use '-x checkstyleTest' to exclude the task via command line.

Comment: where exactly in my file would I put `sourceSets`? seems that a lot of the time when I try to add things like this it doesn't work because it's not in the right spot, and I don't quite yet understand what area of the code the docs are referring to.

Comment: see when I add sourceSets = [], it ends up not running checkstyle period, not just not running it for tests